# Missing default templates in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 installed templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 but it has an issue with missing templates in the Installed Templates.
i.e. When I tried to add New Web Site(File -> New -> New Web Site -> Installed Templates => It shows "No Items found".

So I tried fix it by
1. 'devenv /installvstemplates' command which has not worked for me.

check for zip file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033 folder and is contains all the appropriate zip files. Also same for ItemTemplates folder.

Comment: Is there any problem with Visual studio setup ?

Comment: Is the correct version selected in the dropdown version list?